# Pandas equivalent of SQL where on multiple tables

Tags: pandas

What is the pandas equivalent of this SQL text:

```
table a:
group1  group2  value1
a       2       1.1
b       3       1.5

table b:
group1  group2  value2
a       2       1.8
b       3       2.1

SELECT a.group1, a.group2, a.value1, b.value2
FROM a, b
WHERE a.group1 = b.group1 and a.group2 = b.group2

result:
group1  group2  value1  value2
a       2       1.1     1.8
b       3       1.5     2.1
```

I have tried merging and joining but on my real dataset every single row gets added, I want just the columns from a separate dataframe that match, as in this SQL example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is the equivalent of an inner join, so how about this?

```
In [79]: a.merge(b, on=['group1','group2'])
Out[79]: 
  group1  group2  value1  value2
0      a       2     1.1     1.8
1      b       3     1.5     2.1
```

Comment: When I do this on my actual dataset I get over 5 million rows returned.  It should be around 30,000.

Comment: @camdenl are you sure you specified the on keyword or `how='inner'`?  This should work (add some non-matching rows to your example and give it a try).

Comment: This is the SQL equivalent, unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for.